# Finding sleepover spots in internet cafes in Japan?

Tags: budget, japan, sleeping

The last time I was in Tokyo without a place to sleep, an incredibly helpful japanese couple guided me to an internet cafe that offered single rooms with a bed-couch for a far cheaper price than any hotel. They even had a shower.

How can I find such places in Japan without relying on helpful strangers?

Is there a way to look them up in advance?

Is there some sign I would recognize when passing by such a place, with only a very cursory knowledge of kanji?

Or is this perhaps a standard offer for certain brands of internet cafes? How would I recognize those?

Or if this really requires some local insider knowledge, what is the correct term to ask the locals for?

Answer (score 12):

Yeah. They're called Manga Cafes, or *mangakissa*, and you need to find if they have seating options - ie reclining, pair seat, party room or more.

[Wikipedia's page on Manga Cafes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga_cafe)

Apparently there's a [search engine for them that lets you specify criteria](http://www.mk-style.com/netcafe/), but I'm getting a Tomcat error when I look - so not sure if it's just temporarily not working or down.

[Sunny Pages also lets you search for them in English](http://www.sunnypages.jp/search/modern_tokyo/manga_internet_cafes), as well as a variety of other types of cafes (Maid cafes, for example).

And [mobile netcafe](http://mobile-netcafe.com/en/) is another location that lets you search for them online by prefecture.

Answer (score 1):

I used this [Tokyo Cheapo](http://tokyocheapo.com/accommodationcat/list-of-the-cheapest-and-most-convenient-manga-and-internet-cafes-in-tokyo/) post to find internet cafes (specifically the Manboo! brand). Manboo! has standard pricing and are relatively easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

Some onsens (public bath) offer accomodation too. You can find them easily, they have a common symbol:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/Japanese_Map_symbol_%28Spa%29.svg/2000px-Japanese_Map_symbol_%28Spa%29.svg.png

And some very cheap options are listed here too: http://justporcupine.com/backpacking-in-japan-sleep/

Comment: It's actually fairly uncommon for onsen to offer cheap accommodation in Japan.  Capsule hotels, on the other hand, tend to offer elaborate bathing facilities as a part of the deal.